# SOLVED Dual Monitor extended display doesn't work properly

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have a second monitor that I have used on my previous laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 as a non-mirrored display (don't know what the name for this mode is), so I know it works.

However on my new laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 it works in mirrored displays mode, but when I untick it, it just stretches the desktop over both screens, making everything very low-res, the top bar disappears, I can't click anything, though the mouse pointer is present and after 30 seconds (thanks god for this feature) it reverts back to the previous state.

I have nvidia 370 drivers and already tried reinstalling them - nothing changed. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION:** Switched back to NVidia 367 and for now everything works just fine (although it didn't work by directly switching to 367 from 370 - had to go back to 364 and then to 367)

Comment: Instead of Nvidia 370 drivers something more stable like 361 Ubuntu recommends or whatever Nvidia recommends is worth a try.

Comment: I agree with @WinEunuuchs2Unix. The nVidia 370.28 driver is still in beta. I haven't been able to get dual monitors working with the 370 driver, but everything works just fine with the 367 driver.

Comment: Thank you @ScottDeagan . I clicked up arrow beside your comment because I believe it was 367 that Nvidia website claimed was their "long lasting stable version" or something akin to that.

Comment: Yep, going back to 367 (though first had to revert to 364) did it.